# namespace std has no member any_of

Tags: c++

I'm trying to see if string contains number. As I was searching on this site, i saw implementation by saying `std::any_of(password.begin(), password.end(), ::isdigit)` and it is supposed to return boolean value, true or false. 
However, visual studio keeps saying thath namespace std has no memeber any_of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::any_of` resides in the `<algorithm>` header which you need to include:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

[Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)